# How to post bulk data to elastic search?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am trying to do bulk insert to elastic search. Below is the code

```
import re
fname = 'meta_info.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(fname)
df = df.iloc[5:9,:]
df.reset_index(inplace = True)
df.rename(columns ={"index":"temp", "investment_name":"names"}, inplace = True)
df['create'] = df["temp"].apply(lambda x: json.dumps({"create":{"_id":x}}))
df["names1"] = df["names"].apply(lambda x: json.dumps({"names":x}))
df['final'] = df['create']+r"@"+ df['names1']

s = df['final'].str.cat(sep = r"@")
s = s+"@"
s1 = re.sub(r"@", r'\n', s)

url = 'http://localhost:9200/my_index/_bulk'
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers1, data= s1)
print(response.content)
```

s1 - Fed into request:

```
{"create": {"_id": 5}}
{"names": "Birla Sun Life Fixed Maturity Plan - Annual  Series 3-Growth"}
{"create": {"_id": 6}}
{"names": "Birla Sun Life Fixed Maturity Plan - Annual Series 1-Dividend"}
{"create": {"_id": 7}}
{"names": "Birla Sun Life Fixed Maturity Plan - Annual Series 1-Growth"}
{"create": {"_id": 8}}
{"names": "Birla Sun Life Fixed Maturity Plan - Quarterly Series II-Dividend"}
```

This is the solution. It works. Looks crazy but it works.

Comment: Why you don't use the python library? It has an helper to build a bulk query. For your question, take a look here http://ndjson.org/

Comment: The solution is same as the question. Minor change was needed. Did it in the question itself.